# Glue Crawler excluding many files from table after running on S3 json GZIP data

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-athena, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a lambda that is ingesting json data from a load balancer and then writing each individual json record with a PUT to a kinesis stream.  The kinesis stream is the producer for kinesis firehose, which deposits GZIP into S3 bucket under prefix 'raw'.  Example JSON record:

```
{"level":"INFO","hash":"3c351293-11e3-4e32-baa2- 
bf810ed44466","source":"FE","hat_name":"2249444f-c3f4-4e3d-8572- 
c38c3dab4848","event_type":"MELT_DOWN","payload":{"checking": "true"}}
```

I created an x-ray trace in the producing lambda so I have an idea of how many PUT request (so each individual JSON record).  In the time period I had this ingestion turned "On", I sent about 18,000 records to kinesis stream.  When I ran the crawler on the table with prefix "raw" ( I used default settings but checked in "Crawlers Output" section "Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table." to avoid the HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH.  The crawler runs and successfully detects the schema, and looks like this:

```
column . data type
level .  string
hash     string
source .  string
hat_name string
event_type string
payload string .    <--- (only nested json field that has lots of possible internal structure)
parition_0  string
partition_1 string
partition_2 string
partition_3 string
```

Once the table is created I notice that there are only about 4,000 records, and it should have about 4 times the amount of records.  Later I reran the crawler and I noticed in the logs that one line says:

INFO : Some files do not match the schema detected. Remove or exclude the following files from the crawler

I examined some of the files excluded, the majority of them had valid JSON data, however one or two the file had truncated json record at the end of the file like so:

```
{"level":"INFO","hash":"3c351293-11e3-4e32-baa2- 
bf810ed44466","source":"FE","hat_name":"2249444f-c3f4-4e3d-8572- 
c38c3dab4848","event_type":"MELT_DOWN","payload":{"checking": 
"true"}}{"level":"INFO","hash":"3c351293-11e3-4e32-baa2- 
bf810ed44466","source":"FE","hat_name":"2249444f-c3f4-4e3d-8572- 
c38c3dab4848","event_type":"MELT_DOWN","payl
```

What do I need to do in glue to have all records loaded into the table, i should have around 18,000 not 4,200?  I think one issue is the schema may not match exaclty on some records?  But I validate in the kinesis producer that it is a valid json strucutre with appropriate top level fields.  The second issue I see is the file with truncated json record?  I am assuming this may be an issue with firehose batching the files?  Any help is appreciated.

Note:  I have tried to manually create the json table defining all top level fields, and I still have the same problem, It only finds around 4,200 entries when I query in athena.

Comment: Okay, figured this out so Im going to share in case anyone else has this issue.  Because the crawler uses The Hive JSON SerDe is used to process JSON data, most commonly events. These events are represented as blocks of JSON-encoded text separated by a new line. The records were not being seperated with new line character, so to fix I appended the new line before each PUT to kinesis.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain how you added the new line charachters? We have json files that are being crawled by Glue to create Athena tables as well, but we're getting the same `"Some files do not match the schema detected. Remove or exclude the following files from the crawler"` error.

Comment: @CorerMaximus what you need to do is when you are writing the record to kinesis or kinesis firehose makesure each json document is appended with "\n" this becomes the delimeter needed for the SerDe.  So example { "hat" : "tophat" } + "\n"

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but my use case is a bit different & the problem is the Glue table is not being created due to this problem, how can I create the table at least in Catalog?